# PHP, MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error:

`Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

From the following code:

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$description = $_GET['description'];
$shortDescription = $_GET['shortDescription'];
$ingredients = $_GET['ingredients'];
$method = $_GET['method'];
//$image = $_GET['image'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$length = $_GET['length'];
$dateAdded = uk_date();
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbname', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('dbname');
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO dbname (id, Name, Description, shortDescription, Ingredients, Method, Length, dateAdded, Username) VALUES ('', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($name),
    mysql_real_escape_string($description),
    mysql_real_escape_string($shortDescription),
    mysql_real_escape_string($ingredients),
    //mysql_real_escape_string($image),
    mysql_real_escape_string($length),
    mysql_real_escape_string($dateAdded),
    mysql_real_escape_string($username));

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: you have comment out `//   mysql_real_escape_string($image),
` your query waits 9 variables you pass it 8

Comment: I am going to be uploading the image another way. The image key is in the table, but a value is not being inserted for it. Could this be a cause?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You have 9 fields listed, but only 8 values. Try adding the method.

Comment: Then you didn't fix the problem. Because that *is* the problem.

Answer (score 13):

The number of column parameters in your insert query is 9, but you've only provided 8 values.

```
INSERT INTO dbname (id, Name, Description, shortDescription, Ingredients, Method, Length, dateAdded, Username) VALUES ('', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
```

The query should omit the "id" parameter, because it is auto-generated (or should be anyway):

```
INSERT INTO dbname (Name, Description, shortDescription, Ingredients, Method, Length, dateAdded, Username) VALUES ('', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
```

Comment: Except all the fields are off by one now.

Answer (score 6):

Your query has 8 or possibly even 9 variables, ie. Name, Description etc. But the values, these things ---> `'', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"`, only total 7, the number of variables have to be the same as the values.

I had the same problem but I figured it out. Hopefully it will also work for you.

Comment: Please note that this question has already been answered. No need to revive a 1.5 year old post unless you can add something new. Thanks for your effort anyway.