# Basic PHP help - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am trying to post into a database table, 3 different bits of information, but I get an error of `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Here's my database table structure:

```
    interestID      int(11) auto_increment                          
    name            varchar(100)                                         
    categoryID      int(11)                                  
    interest_desc   varchar(30)                              
    date            timestamp
```

The form:

```
<form id="form_design" method="post" action="interesting.php">
    <fieldset id="input_1">
        <input type="text" id="username" value="name?"   />
    </fieldset>            
    <fieldset id="input_2">
        <input type="text" id="interest" value="your interest?"  />
    </fieldset>   
    <fieldset id="input_3>
       <select id="cats">
           <option value="">--</option>
           <?php 
               $sql = "SELECT   categoryID, category_desc FROM categories "."ORDER BY category_desc"; $rs = mysql_query($sql);

               while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
               { 
                   echo "<option value=\"".$row['categoryID']."\">".$row['category_desc']."</option>\n  "; }
?>                                                                        
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The php that inserts it into the table retrieves a column count doesn't match value count at row 1

PHP -

```
$interest_user = $_POST['username'];
$interest_name = $_POST['interest'];
$interest_cats = $_POST['cats'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO interests ( interestID, name, categoryID
                , interest_desc, date )
             VALUES( "",'$interest_user' '$interest_cats'
                , '$interest_name', "" ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931900/php-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing a comma between `'$interest_user' '$interest_cats'`

should be

```
'$interest_user', '$interest_cats'
```

more problem :-

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO interests 
(interestID,name,categoryID,interest_desc,date)  VALUES( "",'$interest_user' 
'$interest_cats', '$interest_name',""   ) ")
```

Are you sure you are not getting syntax error?

Should be :-

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO interests 
(interestID,name,categoryID,interest_desc,date)  VALUES( '','$interest_user' 
'$interest_cats', '$interest_name',''   ) ")
```

Basic problem is solved,
your way of insertion is vulnerable for SQL injection

Here are the list you MUST do some reading:- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection

Answer (score 0):

yes, the comma seems to be the culprit. I would also consider a few things, like switching to prepared statements, or using something like sprintf to store your query then execute the query.

```
$query =  sprintf('INSERT INTO interests VALUES('', %s, %s, %s, %s)', $interest_user, $interest_cats, $interest_name);
mysql_query($query);
```

just my personal preference for string formatting.