# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - PHP Sub-Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am running into a problem inserting a subarray array values into a mysql table. I get the following error.

**Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.**

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_tourn_results` (
  `fld_tr` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `fld_id_tr` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `fld_score` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_hole` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_T_Time` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fld_tourn_id_tr`,`fld_gPlayer_id_tr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is a array sample.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fld_tr] => HONDA
            [fld_id_tr] => RoMcI
            [fld_score] => -12
            [fldr_hole] => F
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fld_tr] => HONDA
            [fld_id_tr] => TiWoo
            [fld_score] => -10
            [fld_hole] => F
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fld_tr] => HONDA
            [fld_id_tr] => TiWoo
            [fld_score] => -10
            [fld_hole] => F
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fld_tr] => HONDA
            [fld_id_tr] => TiWoo
            [fld_score] => -10
            [fld_hole] => F
        )
)
```

Here is the code I am using for inserting.

```
<?php
//Each 'sub-array' will become a row in the table
foreach($result as $row){
    $i = 0;
    //3 (not 4!) is the highest key in each sub-array
    while($i <= 3){
        //MySQL likes each value wrapped in apostrophes
        $row[$i] = '\'' . $row[$i] . '\'';
        $i++;
    }
    //Convert the sub-array into a comma-separated string
    $row = implode(",", $row);
    //MySQL query inserts the sub-array into a new row in the table
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_results (fld_tr, fld_id_tr, fld_score, fld_hole) VALUES({$row}) ") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

I get the following error.
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." -Brian Kernighan

Comment: http://htmlfixit.com/cgi-tutes/tutorial_MySQL_Error_Invalid_Query_Column_Count_Does_Not_Match_Value_Count.php

Comment: Where does `$result` come from? If from another query, consider using the [`INSERT … SELECT` syntax instead](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) or even a join instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931900/php-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, each `$row` is an associative array, with the keys fl_tr, fl_id_tr, etc.

In that case, when you say `$row[$i] = '\'' . $row[$i] . '\'';`, you're surrounding absolutely nothing with quotes, because `$row[$i]` is empty. And in addition, it's creating the key `$i` for each row, and setting it to `''`, so you're ending up with eight total values in the array: the four original ones with associative keys, and the new numeric keys with the slashes. That, of course, causes your column count mismatch.

The fun thing you can do with `foreach` loops in PHP is `foreach($row as $key => $value) {`, wherein `$key` and `$value` become the key and value of each element in the array. It works on numeric arrays too.

So you can replace your entire `while` loop (*not* your existing `foreach` loop) with the following:

```
foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    $row[$key] = "'$value'";
}
```

And hopefully that should work for you.

**Edit:** As @DCoder pointed out (see the comment below), it would be a good idea to wrap `mysql_real_escape_string` around `$value` if you haven't already escaped your values when building that array you're using.

Comment: That is mostly correct, but it's not necessarily safe against sql injection, `$row[$key] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";` or PDO is better.

Comment: @DCoder I agree, but didn't add `mysql_real_escape_string` because it wasn't in the original question, and we don't know where the array he's got is coming from. I'll edit it in as a note.