# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I'm getting the following error when I click the "AD RECORD" button:

> INSERT failed: INSERT INTO user_master VALUES('cha' , 'rstein' , 'bar' , 'foo') 
>   Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

from the following code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['first']))
{
    $first = get_post('first');
    $query = "DELETE FROM user_master WHERE first='$first'";
    if(!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "DELETE failed: $query<br />" . 
        mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['last']) && isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['email']))
{
    $first      = get_post('first');
    $last       = get_post('last');
    $email      = get_post('email');
    $user_name  = get_post('user_name');

    $query = "INSERT INTO user_master VALUES" . "('$first' , '$last' , '$user_name' , '$email')";

    if(!mysql_query($query, $db_server)) echo "INSERT failed: $query <br />" . mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

echo <<<END
<form action = "willingLog.html" method="post"><pre>
    First       <input type="text" name="first" />
    Last        <input type="text" name="last" />
    Email       <input type="text" name="email" />
    Username    <input type="text" name="user_name" />
            <input type="submit" value="AD RECORD" />
</pre></form>
    END;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931900/php-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: Same error message, somewhat different cause.  In the other, you could count the columns and see the problem; here, you can't see the number of columns in the `user_master` table (but you can safely predict the number of columns is not 4).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your database table has more columns then you are inserting into so you're getting error. (You're probably not representing your userID field which probably is your primary key). You need to specify which fields the data is for in your query:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO user_master (first_name, last_name, user_name, email) VALUES" . "('$first' , '$last' , '$user_name' , '$email')";
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer.  Yes, there is an id field that i didn't use because I thought it would auto increment.  I don't, however, understand the last part of your answer.  Can you elaborate a bit please?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your `user_master` table has any primary key like `id` or `user_id`, then you can do two things:

- You can add auto_increment attribute on "id" field
- Add primary value for "id".

Comment: the user_master table has an id field and it's set up to auto increment.

Comment: yeah me too... so how the solutions?Because all of my tables are using primary key which is same name :"id":

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... the way I solved it was by making sure to **not put a comma in my integer values**.

so if you are inputing a salary into an html form, do not put commas in the salary figure. (I am following the examples given on tutorials point. i thought the salary box should contain a comma, but it caused this error.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your sql query doesn't have spaces near the staring and ending parenthesis. Below will cause the error you mentioned:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ( email, username ) VALUES ($userEmail,$username)"
```