# MySQL column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into a MySQL table using PHP, but getting the error

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO file (id, filename, extention, filelink, filesize, filepass) VALUES('{$random}', '{$filename}', '{$extension}', '{$filelink}', '{$filesize}' '{$filepass}') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Missing a comma after `'{$filesize}'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, MySQL error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931900/php-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: @ Jeremy Smyth thanks a lot.your comment benefited me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO file (id, filename, extention, filelink, filesize, filepass) VALUES('{$random}', '{$filename}', '{$extension}', '{$filelink}', '{$filesize}' '{$filepass}') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

You should add the missing comma after {$filesize}:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO file (id, filename, extention, filelink, filesize, filepass) VALUES('{$random}', '{$filename}', '{$extension}', '{$filelink}', '{$filesize}', '{$filepass}') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 7):

`'{$filesize}' '{$filepass}'` is being considered as a single value since you're missing the comma. Your query would look like:

```
INSERT INTO file (id, filename, extention, filelink, filesize, filepass)
VALUES ( '{$random}',
         '{$filename}',
         '{$extension}',
         '{$filelink}',
         '{$filesize}' '{$filepass}')
```

There. You have 6 columns and 5 values. The column count doesn't match the value count and hence MySQL throws an error message.