# Inserts MySQL when column count doesn't match

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert into a table. My table has id (PK), column1, column2, column 3, column4.

Columns 3 and 4 are from a join and present in table2.

My SQL looks as follows

```
INSERT INTO table3 (SELECT column1 , column2, column3, column4 FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id)
```

but I am getting the following error

## 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I can see this is because I do not have the id in my select. I am unsure how i am supposed to do this as I want the id (pk) to be auto generated.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683732/mysql-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1

Comment: (select 0, column1, column2, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you should try to query like this

```
INSERT INTO table3(column1,column2,column3,column4) SELECT column1 , column2, column3, column4 FROM `table1` LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks