# Hibernate : Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, database-administration

I am using Hibernate 5 and Spring 4. Executing the following SQL Query and getting error

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value
>   count at row 1

```
SQLQuery query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(" update irms_deleted_data SET reason=:reasonStr WHERE  irms_id=:id ");
        query.setString("reasonStr", "ABCD1234");
        query.setInteger("id", irmsData.getId());
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: The posted code looks fine

Comment: Doesn't `createSqlQuery` create a native query, so you have to use quotes for your string field? Like this: `... set reason = ':reasonStr'...`

Comment: Hi Patrick, no we don't have to put quotes around :reasonStr

Comment: Please check you are not doing something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931900/php-mysql-error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1

Answer (score 0):

I tried following (simple hibernate example)

create table irms_deleted_data (reason varchar2(10), irms_id number(11,0));
insert into IRMS_DELETED_DATA values ('xyz', 1);

Wrote a function:

```
private void updateirmsDeletedData() {
Transaction tx = null;
Session session = factory.openSession();
try {
tx = session.beginTransaction();
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("update irms_deleted_data SET reason=:reasonStr WHERE  irms_id=:id");
query.setString("reasonStr", "ABCD1234");
query.setInteger("id", 1);
query.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
}
```

and that worked....

Also can you check if there is a trigger on irms_deleted_data which is doing something that is causing the issue...